# De-allocate memory of structs inside a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, free

I have built a program that have severals structs inside it. We have the "base" struct called Booking that is going to contain all information needed for making a reservation at a vacation location. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char forename[NAME_LEN];
    char surname[NAME_LEN];
    char socialNr[SOCIAL_NR];
    int nrOfPerson;
    Person arrPerson[MAX_GUEST];
    int rentPeriod[2];
    int totalCost;
    Cabin *cabin;
    int seniorCard;
    int juniorCard;
    int childCard;

} Booking;
```

Booking also contains 2 other structs, one array of Persons that will hold up to 8 people max that can be in a booking, and also a struct for a Cabin.
Both of these ones looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char forename[NAME_LEN];
    char surname[NAME_LEN];
    char socialNr[SOCIAL_NR];
    Skicard *ptrSkicard;
    int age;

} Person;

 typedef struct {
    int nr;
    int cost;
    int booked[WEEKS];
    int typeOfCabin;

} Cabin;
```

And the person struct also holds an additional struct for a skicard which looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int price;

} Skicard;
```

My questions is how I now correctly de-allocate the memory of all of these ones when they are inside each other?

I have started and I thought I have to go from inside an move out so I tried to remove all the skicards first, then I would remove the Persons, and then the cabin and last the booking itself.

```
void removeBooking(Booking *booking)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < booking->nrOfPerson; i++)
    {
        free(booking->arrPerson[i].ptrSkicard);
    }
    free(booking);
    printf("%d", booking->nrOfPerson);
}
```

But I'm stuck here. How do I do this properly?

Edit: Forgot to show how the allocation was done.

```
    Booking *allBookings = (Booking *)malloc(sizeof(Booking) * 1);
    Cabin *ptrCabin = (Cabin *)malloc(sizeof(Cabin) * 1);
    Skicard *ptrSkicard = (Skicard *)malloc(sizeof(Skicard) * 1);
```

Comment: If you manage to allocate correctly, do free the same way - backwards.

Comment: The key points are one free per allocation, and make sure you don't try to access anything after you've freed it (which often means freeing in the reverse order of allocation).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sounds like what I was thinking. So first Skicard, then loop through all Person, then cabin and last Booking.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're allocating a `Skicard` but for each person, delete the `Skicard`.  Then delete the Cabin; then delete the Booking.  You should probably not be storing the SSN (social number) in a database — it is rather sensitive PII (personal identifying information).  If you must store it, it should be encrypted — which is harder than you'd expect to do the job well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler About the SSN you are correct. But in this case since it's a school project we are allowed to not encrypt it because it will only hold dummie data. 
But why should I not allocate a Skicard for each person?

Comment: You shouldn't allocate a single Skicard per person because on a 64-bit system, the pointer is bigger than the data.

Comment: Okay. Just thought it would be handy to built it this way but I didn't think about the sizes and internal struture.

Comment: Part of your education needs to be an awareness of security and privacy issues.  It needn't be more than a passing comment — `/* socialNr should be encrypted — EU GDPR 2018 */` or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please note that some structures, i.e.

```
Person arrPerson[MAX_GUEST];
```

are integral part of `Booking` structure and should not be neither allocated nor deallocated -- those will be allocated/deallocated with `Booking` structure.

But the structures we keep just a pointer to, i.e.:

```
Skicard *ptrSkicard;
```

or

```
Cabin *cabin;
```

should be allocated and deallocated.

Basically you should deallocate in reverse order of your allocation. For example, allocation could be:

```
malloc Booking
malloc Skicards in a loop
malloc Cabin
```

So the deallocation should be in reverse, i.e.:

```
free Cabin
free Skicards in a loop
free Booking
```

Comment: This was very helpful!
I don't understand that part of person though, but can read up on that now that you have explained

Comment: @anderssinho there is an array of  `Person` structures, not an array of pointers. This whole array with `Person` structures will be allocated during `Booking` allocation. To have an array of pointers we should use `Person *arrPerson[MAX_GUESTS]` Then we would need to allocate each `arrPerson` element. But since we have an array of structures, it is allocated/deallocated with the whole `Booking` structure.

Comment: Thanks I understand the difference now

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
void removeBooking(Booking *booking)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < booking->nrOfPerson; i++)
    {   
        free(booking->arrPerson[i].ptrSkicard);
        booking->arrPerson[i].ptrSkicard = NULL;
    }
    free(booking->cabin);
    booking->cabin = NULL
    free(booking);
}
```

Set the `booking` pointer to `NULL`, in the caller function, after calling `removeBooking()` function or as an alternative you can pass the address of booking pointer and dereference it while freeing other associated allocations and at the end of `removeBooking()` set `*booking = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You've freed memory taken by `Booking`  (pointed by `booking` ), then you tried to access it.

```
free(booking);
printf("%d", booking->nrOfPerson);
```

It's an undefined behavior. Not sure what you want to accomplish here, because your deallocation doesn't change `nrOfPerson` or `ptrSkicard`. `free()` doesn't change pointer.

Note that your function passes point by value, so you can't change pointer outside of it. if you need that, then:

```
void removeBooking(Booking **booking)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (*booking)->nrOfPerson; i++)
    {
        free((*booking)->arrPerson[i].ptrSkicard);
    }
    free((*booking)->cabin);
    free(*booking);
    *booking = NULL;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Okay so it will de-allocate the memory created for the other structs also?

Comment: @anderssinho no, your concept to free() all pointers is right one., yet it doesn't change them, it just makes memory inaccessible.

Comment: Okay I don't understand now. How should I do then to avoid memory leak and make remove the booking?

Comment: @anderssinho you didn't had leak. you had access to deallocated memory and probably algorithmic flaw due to non-null pointers

Comment: Why `*booking->nrOfPerson`?  You probably mean `(*booking)->nrOfPerson` (and similarly for other references).  You also zap the booking pointer to NULL without freeing it — I sense a memory leak here.  And I don't see the Cabin being freed — another leak?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler er, yes.. just problem to focus on code and typing on phone's keyboard at same time

Answer (score 0):

```
void removeBooking(Booking *booking)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < booking->nrOfPerson; i++)
   {
      free(booking->arrPerson[i].ptrSkicard);
   }
   memset(&booking,0,sizeof(booking));
   printf("%d", booking->nrOfPerson);
}
```

if you are going to free booking(structure),then you can memset like above
once check this.thanks

Comment: Oh have to check what memset does. I thought I needed to use the free() function to remove memory allocated dynamically?

Comment: that doesn't free Booking

Comment: malloc,realloc,calloc are some types you can also go through.once check any one of the above is working for you,if yes then let me know.thanks@Swift